Can I see Pull Request comments in Emacs using Magit and Forge?
I am still pretty new to using Magit and Forge in emacs, but I have not found an answer to this question in the docs or videos.
Here is the situation. So I have a draft pull request submitted on Github, and someone has reviewed the Pull Request and made some comments on some of the changes. I was wondering if there is a way to view those reviewer comments in Magit or in Emacs? That way I don't have to keep flipping back and forth between Emacs, and the github window. Also, is there a way to add comments to those conversations--such as indicating that the comment is resolved, etc.
Note that I did find the code-review package (https://github.com/wandersoncferreira/code-review), and there are a few others. But I am not sure about the maintenance status. The code-review package has not been updated in 2 years--according to github commit history, hence I am not sure which packages are valid or not.
Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Forge does not implement that yet. I plan to implement that eventually, but cannot give you a timeline more precise than "it will probably be quite a while".
This fork of code-review, is used by Doom Emacs, and probably works.
